source not found in ubuntu docker container when installing ruby
i'm trying to setup a jekyll project via docker. I need Ruby 3.1 and newer, but after trying to do source ~/.profile I get an error:

source not found

Here's my dockerfile, what am i missing
FROM ubuntu:22.04

LABEL maintainer="STS Commercial"

ARG NODE_VERSION=18

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

RUN apt-get update \
    && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings \
    && apt-get install -y git curl autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm6 libgdbm-dev libdb-dev gnupg ca-certificates zip unzip libcap2-bin libpng-dev dnsutils librsvg2-bin fswatch ffmpeg nano  \
    && curl -sS 'https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c' | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg > /dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.3-cli php8.3-dev \
       php8.3-gd \
       php8.3-curl \
    && curl -sLS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_VERSION.x nodistro main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && apt-get install -y ruby-full \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential \
    && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev \
    && apt-get update \
    && curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable \
    && rvm install 3.1.2 \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN source ~/.profile \
    && rbenv install 3.1.0 \
    && rbenv global 3.1.0 \
    && gem install jekyll bundler \

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 4000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]


Not an answer to your actual question but I noticed you are installing rvm and then trying to use rbenv (which you have not installed), so that is likely to cause issues of its own.

Also note that environment variables you set in a RUN command (via export, ., or non-standard source) don't persist beyond the end of that RUN command.  This makes version managers tricky to use in Docker.  Can you run this task in a separate image built FROM ruby:3.1.0?

While building a Docker image the default shell used is sh which unlike bash does not support the source builtin but the . operator.
At this point you have two options:

Stick with default Docker build shell sh and replace source ~/.profile by . ~/.profile
Specify an other Docker build shell like bash at the beginning of the Dockerfile before running commands: SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]


. is a POSIX-standard Bourne shell feature.  Even in shells that happen to support source, I always use . instead.
